# What makes a kubernetes node unhealthy?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We've experienced 4 `AUTO_REPAIR_NODES` events(revealed by the command `gcloud container operations list`) on our GKE cluster during the past 1 month. The consequence of node-auto-repair is that the node gets recreated and gets attached a new external IP, and the new external IP, which was not whitelisted by third-party services, eventually caused failure of services running on that the new node.

I noticed that we have "**Automatic node repair**" enabled in our Kubernetes cluster and felt tempted to disable that, but before I do that, I need to know more about the situation.

My questions are:

1. What are some common causes that makes a node unhealthy in the first place? I'm aware of this article https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-repair#node_repair_process which says, "a node reports a **NotReady** status on consecutive checks over the given time threshold" would trigger auto repair. But what could cause a node to become **NotReady**?
2. I'm also aware of this article https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#node-status which mentions the full list of node status: {OutOfDisk, Ready, MemoryPressure, PIDPressure, DiskPressure, NetworkUnavailable, ConfigOK}. I wonder, if any of {OutOfDisk, MemoryPressure, PIDPressure, DiskPressure, NetworkUnavailable} becomes true for a node, would that node becomes NotReady?
3. What negative consequences could I get after I disable "Automatic node repair" in the cluster? **I'm basically wondering whether we could end up in a worse situation than auto-repaired nodes and newly-attached-not-whitelisted IP**. Once "Automatic node repair" is disabled, then for the pods that are running on an Unhealthy node that would've been auto-repaired, would Kubernetes create new pods on other nodes?

Comment: Did you consider something like this: https://serverfault.com/questions/907189/stable-public-ip-or-ip-range-for-outbound-connections-in-gke

Answer (score 1):

The confusion lies here in that there are 'Ready' and 'NotReady' states that are shown when you run `kubectl get nodes` which are reported by the kube-apiserver. But these are independent and unclear from the docs how they relate to the kubelet states described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#node-status)
You can also see the kubelet states (in events) when you run `kubectl describe nodes`

To answer some parts of the questions:

1. As reported by the kube-apiserver

   - Kubelet down
   - docker or containerd or crio down (depending on the shim you are using)
   - kubelet states - unclear.
2. For these, the kubelet will start evicting or not scheduling pods except for Ready (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/). Unclear from the docs how these get reported from the kubeapi-server.
3. - You could have nodes on your cluster not being used and you'd be paying for that usage.
   - Yes, k8s will reschedule the pods after a certain readiness probes fail (configurable). If the kubelet is down or the node down k8s will think the pods are down.
   - Assuming your nodes go down, you could end up with less capacity than what you need to schedule your workloads to k8s would not be able to schedule them anyway.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is there any official document that describes the mechanism "when any of OutOfDisk, MemoryPressure, PIDPressure, DiskPressure, NetworkUnavailable is true, then the node status becomes NotReady"? I was hoping to find that.

Comment: And, when MemoryPressure condition is true, instead of destroying and recreating the entire node, why doesn't kubernetes simply evict/delete certain application pods(and restart the pod on another node) to reclaim resource? Evicting some pods sounds less destructive than recreating the entire node.

Comment: Nah, couldn't find any exact docs. I was looking at the code but will take me time to correlate the states. I modified the answer.  Basically, your node can be ready if the kubelet is up but as soon as on the states of pressure show up then the kubelet will start evicting. I'll take a stab at the code and see if i can find the exact correlation. or you can ask the question on sig-node.

Comment: Looked at the code a bit. Changed the answer, still not clear how what you see when you run `kubectl get nodes` gets translated into kubelet node states.

Answer (score 0):

Not my answer, but this answer on SF points in the right direction, regarding using a NAT gateway and whitelisting that IP
https://serverfault.com/a/930963/429795